# Meteor: Load scss files in a certain order

Tags: meteor, sass

I'd like to know how to load scss files in order when using Meteor.

Not using Meteor, I would make something like `application.scss` and load `.scss` files in order so that stylesheets loaded later can depend on mixins/variables loaded earlier. And then I'd load `application.scss` in my template.

*application.scss*

```
@import 'bourbon/bourbon'
@import 'colors' // where I define color variables

...

// import other stylesheets that depend on `bourbon` and `colors`
```

But I can't do this because Meteor loads all the stylesheets automatically in an unspecified order.

I tried to place `bourbon` and `colors` inside `client/lib` so that they are loaded first, but I can not make use of the mixins/variables defined in them in other stylesheets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Thanks. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss

Very popular and actively-managed package for SCSS users.